# Output HTML in Jquery at a specific index

Tags: jquery, arrays

I getting stuck on a problem with jquery.

I want to have an HTML output on a specific array index coming from an input field.

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="ean[]">
<input type="text" name="serial[]">
</td>
<td class="article[]"></td>
</tr>

$('input[name^="ean"]').change(function(event) {
   var index = $('input[name^="ean"]').index( this );
   $('.article:eq(index)').html("test");
});
```

The aim is, that jquery puts a specific value on an index (class article) after an input field (ean) has changed.

With this code there is no output at the current changed index.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method or concatenate the index value.

```
$('input[name^="ean"]').change(function(event) {
   var index = $('input[name^="ean"]').index( this );
   $('.article\\[\\]').eq(index).html("test");
});
```

---

```
$('input[name^="ean"]').change(function(event) {
   var index = $('input[name^="ean"]').index( this );
   $('.article\\[\\]:eq(' + index + ')').html("test");
});
```

---

Although it's always better cache the jQuery object for future use.

```
var $art = $('.article\\[\\]');
var $inp = $('input[name^="ean"]').change(function(event) {
   var index = $inp.index(this);
   $art.eq(index).html("test");
});
```

**FYI :** The class name includes `[]` at the end so you need to include it in the selector, although you need to escape both since square bracket has special meaning.

Or alternatively, remove the `[]` from the class name and use it as usual, personally I would prefer this.

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="ean[]">
<input type="text" name="serial[]">
</td>
<td class="article"></td>
</tr>

var $art = $('.article');
var $inp = $('input[name^="ean"]').change(function(event) {
   var index = $inp.index(this);
   $art.eq(index).html("test");
});
```

Comment: :D now you concatenated also my answer with yours not just the `index`..

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki : previously I'd added it as a comment line ... and now split up to 2....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick response.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

I tested the td fields with the appropriate class name with:

```
$('td[class^="article"]').html('test');
```

With this, of course, it puts 'test' on all positions.

After trying it with

```
$('.article:eq(' + index + ')').html("test");
```

there's no output.

There's also no output, if I try to label a fix index, like

```
$('.article:eq(0)').html("test");
```

Could it be a problem with eq and my used jquery version (1.10.3)?